# Is there an XPS viewer that can be built into a web page, as iPaper can?

Tags: java, xps, xpsdocument, xpsviewer

Does anyone know of a an XPS viewer that can be built into a webpage that would access XPS files hosted on our server in the same way that iPaper does for pdfs? (Coming up with an automated conversion process for these XPS files to PDF has proven quite difficult.)

Thanks a bunch,
Jake

Answer (score -1):

There are applications that do use what I believe is the XPSViewer IE plug-in e.g. AutoDesk's Design Review. Maybe, you can give this a try/talk to MS directly. They would be more than happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an easy, automated way to convert XPS into PDF, take a look at our NiXPS Converter SDK: http://nixps.com/library.html

It works without the klugde of needing a printer driver installed on the server, it's a pure DLL solution. And we have a .NET api too.